# Swift : Change Tableview Width to 1/2 its size

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swrevealviewcontroller

I followed this tutorial with no success cause its in objective-C 
:

http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/implementing-container-containment-sliding-menu-controller--mobile-14562

[image]

How to change tableview's size in SWRevealViewController Rt. Menu to 1/3 or 1/2 of its size?

```
tableView.frame = CGRectMake(50, 210, self.view.frame.size.width/2, self.view.frame.size.height)
```

another try

```
tableView.frame = CGRectMake(tableView.frame.origin.x, tableView.frame.origin.y, self.view.frame.size.width/2, self.view.frame.size.height)
```

Answer (score 4):

**Customizing the Menu**

The SWRevealViewController class provides a number of options for configuring the sidebar menu. Say, if you want to change the width of the menu, you can update the value of rearViewRevealWidth property. Try to insert the following line of code in the viewDidLoad method of NewsTableViewController:

```
self.revealViewController().rearViewRevealWidth = 62
```

Follow Details here http://www.appcoda.com/sidebar-menu-swift/